# Sculpt brushes working backwards (normals are fine)

Tags: sculpting

Is there any reason my sculpt brushes would substract when add is selected and viceversa?

I checked the normals, but they're fine, I even recalculated them. I started using the inverted brushes but some of them don't work in these circumstances.

EDIT:
I tried sculpting on a remeshed cube, a completely new mesh, and the problem persists. I don't understand :( It even happens between .blend files so I don't know where I messed up.

[image]

[image]

[image: Face orientation on only shows the inside]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Even if you said that the normals are fine, could you share a screenshot with face orientation on?

Comment: It is on, actually. It only makes the inner faces red though, is it supposed to show the other side too? Added a picture @Emir

Comment: It's strange, color of brush is opposite of selected option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I solved it. Apparently it was an error caused by my tablet (xppen deco 03) in conjuction with windows ink activating out of nowhere. I disabled Windows ink and rebooted my computer to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, but it was only on one mesh. What was causing it was that the x scale was set to -1 for some reason. I fixed this by applying scale (Ctrl+A, Scale), then recalculating normals (Shift+N). I know that you always want to apply scale before sculpting, I had forgotten this step.